# TensorFlow: tf.placeholder and tf.Variable - why is the dimension not required?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am learning TensorFlow from the example at: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/2_BasicModels/linear_regression.ipynb

I have a few questions in the code below:
When defining the placeholders and variables like X, Y, W, and b, why didn't we need to specify the dimension of them? How would the code allocate memory without knowing the size of these placeholders/variables? Thanks!

```
    # tf Graph Input
    X = tf.placeholder("float")
    Y = tf.placeholder("float")

    # Set model weights
    W = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="weight")
    b = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="bias")


    # Construct a linear model
    pred = tf.add(tf.mul(X, W), b)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TensorFlow's [`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/placeholders#placeholder) tensors do not require you to specify a shape, in order to allow you to *feed* tensors of different shapes in a later [`tf.Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/client/session_management#Session.run) call. By default, a placeholder has a completely unconstrained shape, but you can constrain it by passing the optional `shape` argument. For example:

```
w = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)                      # Unconstrained shape
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None])  # Matrix of unconstrained size
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 32])    # Matrix with 32 columns
z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[128, 32])     # 128x32-element matrix
```

When you create a placeholder, TensorFlow does not allocate any memory. Instead, when you feed the placeholder, in the call to `tf.Session.run()`, TensorFlow will allocate appropriately sized memory for the input (and subsequently for any necessary intermediate) tensors.

Note that [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/variables#Variable) objects typically do require a shape when you create them, and this shape is inferred from the first argument to the initializer. In your program, `rng.randn()` (an alias for [`numpy.random.randn()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html)) returns a scalar value, and so the variables `W` and `b` will have scalar shape.

Although the placeholders in your code (`X` and `Y`) have unconstrained shape, some of the operators, such as [`tf.add()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/arithmetic_operators#add) and [`tf.mul()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/arithmetic_operators#multiply), have additional requirements about the shape of their arguments (viz. that they are compatible with the [NumPy broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)). Since TensorFlow doesn't know when you build the graph what the actual shapes of those tensors will be, it trusts that the user knows what they are doing, and performs the check dynamically (during the call to `tf.Session.run()`). If instead you constrain the shapes of the placeholders, you enable TensorFlow to perform some checks earlier, and doing this can help to reduce bugs.

Comment: Thanks! How about the variable case?

Comment: Just saw that you were asking about that too... I updated the answer to explain.

Comment: as I read the code in https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/2_BasicModels/linear_regression.ipynb  It seems to me that the variable W is an array, not a scalar. Am I understanding it wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I am almost certain that it's a scalar. Notice that the log message printed every 50 epochs gives scalar values for `W` and `b`.

Comment: I thought train_X (which is an numpy array) is the input of placeholder X. Then later on it has pred = tf.add(tf.mul(X, W), b). If X is an array, W should be an array. Unless X is also a scalar? It is just input X from train_X n-sample times?

Comment: I think in this case the NumPy array `train_X` and the TensorFlow placeholder `X` represent vectors (1-D arrays). In both NumPy and TensorFlow, if you multiply a vector of N values by a scalar (as `W` is here), the scalar is [broadcasted N times](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) along the vector.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131633/discussion-between-edamame-and-mrry).

Comment: unrelated, but @mrry it would be a good idea to start a TensorFlow chatroom

Comment: You say: "Note that tf.Variable objects typically do require a shape when you create them"
This implies that there are cases where that you do not; but I can't find them. Can you describe these cases, or, if that is incorrect, change the wording to be definitive?

Comment: Creating a variable with `tf.Variable(..., validate_shape=False)` will disable shape inference from the initial value, and allow you to use `var.assign(..., validate_shape=False)`. It isn't a very common use case, however.